# Viewer for very large image sets

Tags: imagej, image-stitching, fiji

I'm looking for a viewer that can view thousands of images selectively. For example, I have a set of photos from 1-1000. Due to the magnitude of the photos (8MB per image), I only wish to view photos 20-40. This is to be done with selecting specific coordinates of the photos.

**What I have done:**
-Tried the plugin BigDataViewer on ImageJ (FIJI) however, this cannot work because it can only view stitched images, but I wish to extract the chosen images before stitching. However, is there another way I can use BigDataViewer for this task?